# Using Routing in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, routes, react-native-router-flux

I have button as mentioned below and I have an another page named JobDetails on the same folder in the project. When I click on the button "next" i need to display that JobDetails page. I have added onButtonPress with alert function and it works fine. I'm not sure on how to bring the next page on clicking the button using routing.

```
onButtonPress(){
    alert("Prem")
}

<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onButtonPress.bind(this)} style={styles.buttonStyle} >
    <Text style={styles.nextPage}>
        Next
    </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple for [react-native-router-flux](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux), just do:

```js
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';

onButtonPress(){
  Actions.JobDetails();
}
```

Make sure your `Scene` key is correct (JobDetails in your case).

```js
<Scene key="JobDetails" component={JobDetails} />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using [Stack Navigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/stack#StackNavigator) from `react-navigation`

**Installation**:
 `npm install --save react-navigation`

**Example**:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

class MyHomeScreen extends React.Component {

    static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'Home'
    }


    onButtonPress(){
        this.props.navigation.navigate('JobDetails'); // navigate to JobDetails screen!
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onButtonPress.bind(this)} style={styles.buttonStyle} >
                <Text style={styles.nextPage}>
                    Next
                </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    }
}

class JobDetailsScreen extends React.Component {

    static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'Job Details'
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>I'm job screen!</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const ModalStack = StackNavigator({
    Home: {
        screen: MyHomeScreen
    },
    JobDetails: {
        screen: JobDetailsScreen
    }
});

export default ModalStack;
```

Comment: Thank you, but I',m stuck with the error "this.props.navigation.navigate undefined is not an object"

Comment: Replace `onPress={this.onButtonPress.bind(this)} ` with `onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('JobDetails')}`